# How to force gcc generate bare asm code (do not use pseudo code)

Tags: gcc, assembly

e.g. MIPS:

I use  `gcc -S xx.c`

gcc gens : `move xxx`

but I want real instruction `sll xxx`

Maybe a simple question, but I didn't find the answer on Google.

**EDIT:**

gcc want to gen a `move` insn, but in mips there is no real `move` , it use `sll $x, $x, $0` to do `move` things. also it use `sll $0, $0, $0` to do `nop` things.

Comment: Can you please provide the code for which you are seeing these instructions? The values for the variables being moved might give a clue as to why gcc is using a `move` instead of a a `sll`

Comment: Pretty sure the command in question is `gcc -S xx.c`. That's the capital S, not the lowercase s. Does that help?

Comment: @susmits: You are right, thanks, It's a mistake on my typing:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`move` is a [pseudo-instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Pseudo_instructions) in MIPS assembly. It's not a real instruction, but the assembler accepts it and translates it.

`move $rt, $rs` translates to `addi $rt, $rs, 0`.

As for making gcc output assembly code with no pseudo-instructions, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: yes, I mean I want it to gen all real-insn like sll not the move, even it accept it.

Comment: @Wu you'll have to translate it manually (or in your head), unfortunately. GCC produces pseudoinstructions and there's no way to turn this off.